# How to output string values in single quotes?

Tags: postgresql, string

I'm trying to convert values stored in a json into its string representation.

The `#>>` operator works for this purpose for numbers, e.g.:

```
SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":["4","5","6"]}'::json#>>'{a,2}';
```

gives

```
 ?column? 
------
 3
(1 row)
```

But for string values, the text representation (`6` in the example below) does not have single quotes around it, so that one cannot tell that the stored value was a string:

```
SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":["4","5","6"]}'::json#>>'{b,2}';
 ?column? 
----------
 6
(1 row)
```

How to use a function or expression to let PostgreSQL output `'6'` instead of `6` in the second example above (and output `3` in the first example)?

(This is with PostgreSQL 12)

*-- UPDATE --*

@McNets

To clarify, I am interested in getting the string representation in quotes, so that after decomposing a jsonb into its key value pairs, one can use them with inverse functions like `jsonb_build_object` (so to speak) to reconstruct the original jsonb.

`jsonb_each_text` and the `#>>` apparently aren't good enough because they drop the single quotes.

Comment: Why do you need quoted values?

Comment: Operator `#>>` will output text type. That is the reason `6` is not quoted. You can use `to_json` or `json_each`/`jsonb_each` to keep the quote.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than retrieving the value as `text` with `#>>`, use `#>` to retrieve it as `json` and cast it to `text` afterwards:

```
SELECT ('{"a":[1,2,3],"b":["4","5","6"]}'::json#>'{b,2}')::text;

 text 
------
 "6"
(1 row)
```

There is also the `json_typeof` function that can tell you what JSON type the value has:

```
SELECT json_typeof('{"a":[1,2,3],"b":["4","5","6"]}'::json#>'{b,2}');

 json_typeof 
-------------
 string
(1 row)
```